# how to center 3d camera vertically and horizontally

Tags: 3d, camera, movement, godot

How to center the `player/camera` in the middle of the `window/screen` , to mimic a `2.5d` camera, so it looks like this game:

[image]

where I can move vertically and horizontally , and the camera still be centered on the player?

Edit: I want to center it 18 pixels in the 4 directions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Follow position**

What first comes to mind is to use a `RemoteTransform`. You can set its remote path is the player avatar, and to only update the position (not the rotation, not the scale). Then make the `Camera` a child of the `RemoteTransform` and give it is rotation and offset position.

I suggest to use the split view (click View on the top of the editor and select Two Viewports) and then use one to preview the camera and the other to move it.

---

**Follow x and z**

Sadly `RemoteTrasnform` does not gives you the granularity to say that you want to follow the x and z but not the y. However we can mimic it:

```
tool
extends Spatial

export var remote_path:NodePath
export var y:float

func _process(_delta: float) -> void:
    var target = get_node_or_null(remote_path) as Spatial
    if !is_instance_valid(target):
        return # either null or freed

    var target_position = target.global_transform.origin
    var position = Vector3(target_position.x, y, target_position.z)
    global_transform = Transform.IDENTITY.translated(position)

func _get_configuration_warning() -> String:
    var target = get_node_or_null(remote_path) as Spatial
    if is_instance_valid(target):
        return ""
    
    return "The \"Remote Path\" property must point to a valid Spatial or Spatial-derived node to work."
```

Set the Remote Path to the player avatar. And, of course, you make the `Camera` a child of that node, and rotate and offset it appropriately.

---

**Isometric view**

Advice if you want the isometric view: The rotation you want 45 degrees (or 135, 225, 315) on y, and -35.264 on x. Set projection to Orthogonal. You may have to adjust the Size of the camera which controls how much you see in the Orthogonal projection.

---

**Margins**

This took some figuring out. I'll go over the script part by part explaining what is going on.

```
tool extends Spatial
```

It is `Spatial` because 3D.

The reason why it is a `tool` script is to give those warnings that appear on the scene tree. We do that by implementing `_get_configuration_warning`. Let us get `_get_configuration_warning` out of the way:

```
func _get_configuration_warning() -> String:
    var target = get_node_or_null(remote_path) as Spatial
    if !is_instance_valid(target):
        return "The \"Remote Path\" property must point to a valid Spatial or Spatial-derived node to work."
    
    return ""
```

---

These are the variables we will export:

```
export var remote_path:NodePath
export var y:int
export var margin:Vector2 = Vector2.ZERO
```

The variable `remote_path` is the `NodePath` to what the camera should follow. The variable `y` is the value for `y` we use in the transform (because we only take `x` and `z`). And the variable `margin` is how far off center on the screen we allow what we are following to go before we begin moving.

---

I have gone back and forth between whether or not we should use `_process` or `_physics_process`. On one hand the player avatar will only update on `_physics_process`. On the other this is about something visual (the Camera). At the end I ended up opting for `_process` because what this node follows might not necessarily be a physics body, and even if it is, it could be using `_process` for interpolation.

Since this is a `tool` script, `_process` begins like this:

```
func _process(_delta: float) -> void:
    if Engine.editor_hint:
        return
```

Similarly we don't want it to run when it isn't in the scene tree:

```
    if !is_inside_tree():
        return
```

Now let us get a reference to the viewport:

```
    var viewport:Viewport = get_viewport()
```

Just in case, let us check it is valid:

```
    if !is_instance_valid(viewport):
        return
```

Now we use it to get *the current* camera:

```
    var camera:Camera = viewport.get_camera()
```

We not only need to check if it is valid, we also need to check if it is the child of this node.

```
    if !is_instance_valid(camera) or camera.get_parent() != self:
        return
```

We also need the the target that the camera should follow:

```
    var target = get_node_or_null(remote_path) as Spatial
    if !is_instance_valid(target):
        return
```

And we are going to need the coordinates of the center of the screen:

```
    var viewport_center := viewport.size * 0.5
```

---

Alright, we get the position we want to follow:

```
    var target_position := target.global_transform.origin
```

We only want `x` and `z`, of course:

```
    var position_3d := Vector3(target_position.x, y, target_position.z)
```

We figure out where on the screen that is:

```
    var position_2d := camera.unproject_position(position_3d)
```

We figure out the difference from the center of the screen:

```
    var off_center := position_2d - viewport_center
```

And we clamp it to the margin:

```
    var off_center_clamped := Vector2(
            clamp(off_center.x, -margin.x, margin.x),
            clamp(off_center.y, -margin.y, margin.y)
        )
```

If clamping did nothing, then we don't need to move:

```
    if off_center == off_center_clamped:
        return
```

Now, a tricky bit:

```
    var target_2d := viewport_center + off_center - off_center_clamped
```

This is the position in 2D that we want to put on the center. Notice that when `off_center` and `off_center_clamped` are equal, then `target_2d` is `viewport_center`. Meaning we want at the center, what is at the center.

However, `off_center` and `off_center_clamped` are different. So `target_2d` will be moved offset from the center according to that difference.

And now another tricky bit:

```
    var ray_origin := camera.project_ray_origin(target_2d)
    var ray_direction := camera.project_ray_normal(target_2d)
```

That's right, we are ray casting. We need to convert that position back to something in 3D.

```
    var depth := (y - ray_origin.y) / ray_direction.y
```

So what's that?

Let us see. We want to track a position on an horizontal plane defined by `y`. So we need to intersect the ray with that plane.

So we have some equation that looks like this:

```
(ray_origin + ray_direction * depth).y = y
```

Let us put some vector there:

```
ray_origin + ray_direction * depth = _target_3d
whatever.y = y
```

Solve for depth:

```
ray_origin + ray_direction * depth = _target_3d
=>
ray_direction * depth = _target_3d - ray_origin
=>
depth = (_target_3d - ray_origin) / ray_direction
```

And we only care about the `y`, so:

```
depth = (whatever.y - ray_origin.y) / ray_direction.y
```

Thus:

```
    var depth := (y - ray_origin.y) / ray_direction.y
```

Alright, we can now figure out that point. Just plug that equation again:

```
    var target_3d := ray_origin + ray_direction * depth
```

Which, by the way, is the same as:

```
    var target_3d := camera.project_position(_target_2d, depth)
```

Except we already did all the work anyway.

Finally, set the transform:

```
global_transform = Transform.IDENTITY.translated(target_3d)
```

---

Usage is as expected. Make this node the parent of the Camera, set its properties. Position the camera.

Comment: is there a way to limit/center the camera , so it's 18 pixels in the 4 directions, so from the center/player to the right edge is 18 , and so on for the other directions ?

Comment: @Abanoub answer extended.

Comment: thank you very much  for this detailed answer, but can you please provide a demo project on github or something, because the camera configuration isn't working, also the fps got drop down to 15 fps, when switched to orthogonal,  a demo would make me compare and match, thanks again

Comment: @Abanoub https://github.com/AbanoubNassem/game/pull/1

Comment: thank you very much , but the player is off a bit to the right, I believe we need to subtract the width of it , so it's 100% centered ?

Comment: @Abanoub not sure what you mean by that. On one hand it has a margin from the center. 100 pixels (because, 18, really?) - And on the other, sure… It is only considering a point. Considering the volume the MeshInstance occupies is more complex (edit: Had a look, it is two MeshInstances). However, that would not be to the right, that would be in every direction.

Comment: Now, what is 100% centered? I give you two options: Make the margin (0,0). Which defeats the point of the script, you could use the simpler one. Or you can edit this line: `var _target_2d = _viewport_center + off_center - off_center_clamped` into this: `var _target_2d = position_2d` and then the motion is not smooth, it teleports every time the avatar moves too much away from the center. I did consider giving it a maximum velocity so it does not teleport (and then if it moves to fast, it might leave the camera behind). Is that what you want? - I did actually try to implement easing, went bad.

Comment: well I'm trying to mimic this game walk/jump mechanics : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2bcnkHKDXk , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c07SMWnGnpM&t=270s , I thought it would be easy using godot , but till this point , I can't make it 100% like those videos  , I don't know it's my lack of experience , or godot doesn't actually offer easy to tools to handle it

Comment: @Abanoub That should be easier in 2D. Where are the 18 pixels? It appears to me that the first script would do. The one I put under "Follow x and z".

Comment: but how would I use 3d meshes in 2d, with performance in mind?!

Comment: @Abanoub You could: 1. Have the 3D camera follow the 2D one. Mixing 2D and 3D is not rare in Godot, we do it all the time for GUI/HUD (Note: both Node2D and Control extend CanvasItem). 2. Render the 3D models to a separate viewport and use them as textures in 2D (you can follow this official demo project: https://github.com/godotengine/godot-demo-projects/tree/master/viewport/3d_in_2d ) 3. Don't. You could do like Donkey Kong Country and Mario Kart 64 where they made sprites from 3D models. 4. Let us figure out what is wrong with 3D. What is this offset to the right you see? And why 18 pixels?

Comment: from past experience, the maximum space/distance from the player to all the edges is 18 pixels, that's why I thought to limit it like they are doing, in the game you basically see far to 18 pixels in all directions, you can't see/walk/jump past that

Comment: @Abanoub I don't see that on the videos. I see it centered (to the position on the ground, as the camera does not follow move up and down with the avatar jump, it only follows x and z). For reference I added a 18 by 18 pixels square: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ik0GW.jpg - For the solution I defined a region in pixels from the center of the screen, and as long as the player stays there the camera does not move: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QG6ik.png I made it 100 pixels in each direction (so it is 200 by 200). And that's why 18 pixels seems to little to me. Again, I don't see that on the videos.

Comment: @Abanoub A couple clarifications: 1. That 100 pixels in each direction you can change it, it is an exported variable in the script. 2. It only cares about the origin of the character, it can go as far as the corner, and that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwjoO.png - Again, I don't see that in the video. Instead it looks to me like the solution I have under "Follow x and z" would work (we ignore the y, because that is the jump, and the camera does not move up and down with the jump). That is the solution I had before any 18 pixels were mentioned. So where are the 18 pixels?

Comment: maybe the 18 pixels is in the 2d mode, I don't know I will try to work with what you have provided me, hopefully I can achieve a decent result